# Shift operator on a Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

I have been the paper titled [Dual Piecewise Analytic Bundle Shift Models of Linear Operators](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0022123696900324?token=93D6C4CCA8A2B6DC6C795926D55AC0A17FEC3A5E7FAC1AB84C26B9C9CC7682FB4B4710826CD6C36802605EB04E083EF8) by Dmitry Yakubovich.

In the second paragraph of the introduction it says "Let $T$ be a bounded Linear operator on a reflexive Banach space $X$. It will  be  assumed  that *$T$ behaves  like  the  shift  operator,  that  is,  that  the eigenvalues of $T^*$ fill in some connected components of the complement of the  essential  spectrum of $T$,  whereas  the  point  spectrum  of $T$ is  empty.*

Can anyone explain why the statement in italics would be true? Why an operator which behaves like a shift operator have such properties? Any reference to theory related to this would be helpful.

Comment: Presumably the shift operator in $l^2$ has such a property.  Then Yakubiovich used this as the definition for "behaves like the shift operator".